# Cross Ambiguity Function Peak Width

Tags: cross-correlation, ofdm, radar

I am trying to plot the Cross Ambiguity Function of two OFDM signal (1024 subcarriers) reflected from two targets, which are separated by 30m.
The problem I am facing that the CAF peak width at the range domain is wide (zero-doppler cut), which means that the range resolution is too low. So, I am just wondering how would it be possible to reduce the peak width to get high range resolution?
(Note that CAF peak width at doppler domain is sharp (zero-delay cut).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a RF system. What is the bandwidth of the waveform? The range resolution $\Delta R$ achieved by a matched-filtered waveform is given by

$$\Delta R = \frac{c}{2\beta}$$

Where $c$ is the speed of light and $\beta$ is the bandwidth of the waveform. A range resolution of 30 m requires a bandwidth of 5 MHz. Is your bandwidth lower than this? If it is, that's your problem: you must increase the bandwidth of the waveform you're transmitting.

Comment: The BW of the baseband ofdm signal is around 1 kHz.

Comment: @wesamamiri Have you tried increasing the bandwidth by adding more channels or widening the current ones? If you do that and then match filter, you should see your lobe sharpen up.

Comment: I am trying to increase the BW, but I am facing some difficulties since I use the matlab  OFDM function.
Is there any way to widen the subcarriers?

Comment: @wesamamiri Would you mind showing your MATLAB code?

Comment: Sure, I can send it to you personally by email if that works for you

Comment: @wesamamiri It would be best if you posted it here as it may help others in the same type of situation. If for any reason you can't, it would be understood, but unfortunately we wouldn't be able to help you further.

Comment: This the code of the transmitted signal, where it is difficult to increase the signal BW because the restriction between the data length and the number of subcarriers.

Comment: @wesamamiri There seems to be an additional question here involving how to do this using MATLAB's toolbox, which is in addition to the theoretical question about range resolution. I personally don't have the one required installed to help at the moment.

Comment: I am just wondering how to increase the BW of the OFDM signal in the code above?
I tried to use WGN signal with high BW, but unfortunately I could not separate the two target's peaks.